# How to increment number in a cell after printing on excel

Tags: excel

I was wondering if some one can help me. I need to increment by one a number in a cell and then clean a few textbox but after the printing. There is an beforeprint event but doesnt do what I want becuase before the sheet is printed all the data is cleaned, obviously (I apologize for my english) Is there a way to do what I need or a better practice for it. Thank you.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
 [I6] = [I6] + 1
 [C11] = ""
 [C12] = ""
 Range("B16:B27").ClearContents
 Range("C16:C27").ClearContents
 Range("D16:D27") = ""
 Range("H16:H27").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe supply a parent worksheet reference to all of those range and cell addresses.

Comment: Typically you'd use the before_print method to do something like setting the print area, i.e. something specific to the act of printing the document. What you're doing is just resetting some fields, which would be better linked to a reset button, so that it is independent of the act of printing. What if you need to print twice because the first one failed? What if you want to print without resetting?

Comment: If you really want to go down the path of linking printing and resetting, just make a 'print and reset' button which does exactly that.

Comment: His code works for me.  Excel 2013 32bit.  It increments the cells and clears the others.  It shows in the PDF (the changes are made BEFORE print).  Here are my results: http://imgur.com/a/hfKle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To act AFTER printing, you need to print the document via VBA's `ActiveSheet.PrintOut` inside of the `BeforePrint` event and set Cancel to true, so it doesn't run its own print too.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

 Cancel = True
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 ActiveSheet.PrintOut
 Application.EnableEvents = True

 [I6] = [I6] + 1
 [C11] = ""
 [C12] = ""
 Range("B16:B27").ClearContents
 Range("C16:C27").ClearContents
 Range("D16:D27") = ""
 Range("H16:H27").ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful. Works great!